# Selenium Webdriver: find_element_by_xpath not locating full path

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium 2.53.6 and Chromedriver to locate HTML DOM elements on a dynamic web page. I am using Webdriver's `find_element_by_xpath()` command to locate the element. When it's a single element like the below example, `find_element_by_xpath()` locates the element.

```
city1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='post-body-meta']")
```

However, when I extend the path to include more elements in the DOM hierarchy:

```
city1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='post-body-meta']/span[0]")
```

then I get the error below (keep in mind I've tried numerous different elements, not just this specific one):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selen_decko.py", line 72, in <module>
    city1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='post-body-meta']/span[0]")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='post-body-meta']/span[0]"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x101468b70>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 173, in __del__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 149, in stop
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 120, in send_remote_shutdown_command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So close, yet so far. I needed `find_elements_by_xpath`. The key difference is `elements` as opposed to `element`. Also, indexing seems to start at 1, not 0:

```
city = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='post-body-meta']/span[1]/a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you validated the xpath by entering via Chrome's inspect tool or Firefox's Firepath add-on?  Without seeing the HTML code I can't be sure the path is valid.